# Diamond facets get dark after adding metal and also facets get invisible?

Tags: rendering

[.blend file link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a0Hb_5ooOSo4DhujD_x01uvmligwh55q?usp=drive_link)[image: Facets of the diamond get dark and invisible after adding metal. Diamond facets are visible if don't add metal.]

Facets of the diamond get dark and invisible after adding metal. Diamond facets are visible if don't add metal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details like material settings, render settings or a sample .blend file for others to test.

Comment: above i have Attached the .blend file

Answer (score 1):

The diamonds are refracting the surrounding objects which is why you see them darkened and dull.
To simulate the behavior of real life diamond will probably take a lot of trials and errors and most likely will never look right.

If you want the diamonds to have the same sparkly look like without the metal frame (where it refracts the environment only) you can apply a small trick.

Edit your ring material "**WhiteMetal.014**". Add the node **Mix Shader** and connect the "**White-Metal**" group and a **Transparent BSDF** to it. As a factor use the **Is Glossy Ray output** of a **Light Path** node.
Here is a before and after look:

*Before*
[image]

*After*
[image]

Comment: Made the changes has you suggested but Facing same issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK52U.jpg

Comment: please share your blend file which you have made changes.

Comment: Your setup is not correct. Change the Translucent Shader to Transparent Shader.

Comment: Thank you so much... Problem Solved